# Thumbor installation not working

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, thumbnails, thumbor

I have followed the wiki and set up everything necessary, but all the images are broken right now. I used the `aptitude` package manager to install.

Here are my configuration files:

**`/etc/default/thumbor`**

```
# set this to 0 to disable thumbor, remove or set anything else to enable it
# you can temporarily override this with
# sudo service thumbor start force=1
enabled=1

# Location of the configuration file
conffile=/etc/thumbor.conf

# Location of the keyfile which contains the signing secret used in URLs
#keyfile=/etc/thumbor.key

# IP address to bind to. Defaults to all IP addresses
# ip=127.0.0.1

# TCP port to bind to. Defaults to port 8888.
# multiple instances of thumbor can be started by putting several ports coma separeted
# Ex:
# port=8888,8889,8890
# or
port=8888 #Default
```

**`/etc/thumbor.conf`**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# thumbor imaging service
# https://github.com/globocom/thumbor/wiki

# Licensed under the MIT license:
# http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license
# Copyright (c) 2011 globo.com timehome@corp.globo.com

# the domains that can have their images resized
# use an empty list for allow all sources
#ALLOWED_SOURCES = ['mydomain.com']
ALLOWED_SOURCES = ['admin.mj.dev', 'mj.dev', 'api.mj.dev', 's3.amazonaws.com']

# the max width of the resized image
# use 0 for no max width
# if the original image is larger than MAX_WIDTH x MAX_HEIGHT,
# it is proportionally resized to MAX_WIDTH x MAX_HEIGHT
# MAX_WIDTH = 800

# the max height of the resized image
# use 0 for no max height
# if the original image is larger than MAX_WIDTH x MAX_HEIGHT,
# it is proportionally resized to MAX_WIDTH x MAX_HEIGHT
# MAX_HEIGHT = 600

# the quality of the generated image
# this option can vary widely between
# imaging engines and works only on jpeg images
QUALITY = 85

# enable this options to specify client-side cache in seconds
MAX_AGE = 24 * 60 * 60

# client-side caching time for temporary images (using queued detectors or after detection errors)
MAX_AGE_TEMP_IMAGE = 0

# the way images are to be loaded
LOADER = 'thumbor.loaders.http_loader'

# maximum size of the source image in Kbytes.
# use 0 for no limit.
# this is a very important measure to disencourage very
# large source images.
# THIS ONLY WORKS WITH http_loader.
MAX_SOURCE_SIZE = 0

# if you set UPLOAD_ENABLED to True,
# a route /upload will be enabled for your thumbor process
# You can then do a put to this URL to store the photo
# using the specified Storage
UPLOAD_ENABLED = False
UPLOAD_PHOTO_STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.file_storage'
UPLOAD_PUT_ALLOWED = False
UPLOAD_DELETE_ALLOWED = False

# how to store the loaded images so we don't have to load
# them again with the loader
#STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.redis_storage'
#STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.no_storage'
STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.file_storage'
#STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.mixed_storage'
# root path of the file storage
FILE_STORAGE_ROOT_PATH = '/var/lib/thumbor/storage'

# If you want to cache results, use this options to specify how to cache it
# Set Expiration seconds to ZERO if you want them not to expire.
#RESULT_STORAGE = 'thumbor.result_storages.file_storage'
#RESULT_STORAGE_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 # one day
#RESULT_STORAGE_FILE_STORAGE_ROOT_PATH = '/tmp/thumbor/result_storage'

RESULT_STORAGE_STORES_UNSAFE=False

# stores the crypto key in each image in the storage
# this is VERY useful to allow changing the security key
STORES_CRYPTO_KEY_FOR_EACH_IMAGE = True

#REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
#REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_PORT = 6379
#REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_DB = 0
#REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_PASSWORD = None

# imaging engine to use to process images
#ENGINE = 'thumbor.engines.graphicsmagick'
#ENGINE = 'thumbor.engines.pil'
ENGINE = 'thumbor.engines.opencv'

# detectors to use to find Focal Points in the image
# more about detectors can be found in thumbor's docs
# at https://github.com/globocom/thumbor/wiki
DETECTORS = [
    'thumbor.detectors.face_detector',
    'thumbor.detectors.feature_detector',
]

# Redis parameters for queued detectors
# REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
# REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_PORT = 6379
# REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_DB = 0
# REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_PASSWORD = None

# if you use face detection this is the file that
# OpenCV will use to find faces. The default should be
# fine, so change this at your own peril.
# if you set a relative path it will be relative to
# the thumbor/detectors/face_detector folder
#FACE_DETECTOR_CASCADE_FILE = 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'

# this is the security key used to encrypt/decrypt urls.
# make sure this is unique and not well-known
# This can be any string of up to 16 characters
SECURITY_KEY = "thumbor@musejam@)!$"

# if you enable this, the unencryted URL will be available
# to users.
# IT IS VERY ADVISED TO SET THIS TO False TO STOP OVERLOADING
# OF THE SERVER FROM MALICIOUS USERS
ALLOW_UNSAFE_URL = False
# Mixed storage classes. Change them to the fullname of the
# storage you desire for each operation.
#MIXED_STORAGE_FILE_STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.file_storage'
#MIXED_STORAGE_CRYPTO_STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.no_storage'
#MIXED_STORAGE_DETECTOR_STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.no_storage'

FILTERS = [
    'thumbor.filters.brightness',
    'thumbor.filters.contrast',
    'thumbor.filters.rgb',
    'thumbor.filters.round_corner',
    'thumbor.filters.quality',
    'thumbor.filters.noise',
    'thumbor.filters.watermark',
    'thumbor.filters.equalize',
    'thumbor.filters.fill',
    'thumbor.filters.sharpen',
    'thumbor.filters.strip_icc',
    'thumbor.filters.frame',

    # can only be applied if there are already points for the image being served
    # this means that either you are using the local face detector or the image
    # has already went through remote detection
    # 'thumbor.filters.redeye',
```

URLs for images that I try to load look like this:

`http://localhost:8888/Q9boJke8j2p2Qtv53Hbz_g1nMZo=/250x250/smart/http://s3.amazonaws.com/our-company/0ea7eeb2979215f35112d2e5753a1ee5.jpg`

I have also setup a key in `/etc/thumbor.key`, please let me know if that's necessary to post here.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket in the filters option in your thumbor.conf.

Did you miss it posting here or actually in the thumbor.conf file?